# How to fill missing category variable?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, analytics, data-science, data-analysis

Instead of mode are there any other way to fill missing categorical variable.
Suppose I have a data set with gender column is missing in such case I can't keep Mode of that column.

Comment: This depends on your logic. *What do you want* for missing data? Keep the ratio of male-to-female for the missing values?

Comment: Is your analysis heavily dependent on this column? Otherwise if your data is of a high dimension, you can choose to substitute it with a third category similar to "others" or "Not Available". In case it affects your model a lot, you can choose to give less weight to the feature.

Comment: How much is missing? If it's more than 30%, drop the variable but if not then train a classifier and predict the missing ones.